# Why if ... else if ... else have common scope? And what scope is common with last else?

Tags: c++, if-statement, scope

TIL that `if` and `else` have common scope:

```
if (int x = foo()) {
  // ....
}
else if (int x = bar()) {
  // ...
}
else {
  cout << x; // which x here?
}
```

I checked ( https://godbolt.org/g/mAvW7B ) that `x` in else is first.

But why? What is the explanation of this non-obvious behavior?

In this example:

```
if (int x1 = foo()) {
  // ....
}
else if (int x2 = bar()) {
  // ...
}
else {
  cout << x2; // why x2 is visible here
}
```

Why `x2` is visible in last `else` then? And why in the first case `x` is from first `if`?

Comment: You are wrong, and your test code can't actually show the difference.

Comment: @SebastianRedl check here: https://ideone.com/5eEzoU

Output is for first x.

Comment: @vladon `int b = bar() > 2` evaluates `bar() > 2`, which is `0`, and initialises `b` to that. This seems to be a mistake in your question unrelated to the actual question you wanted to ask.

Comment: You linked to a perfectly good compilable example but the code you posted here is incomplete. Why? You should turn your warnings up too: `warning C4456: declaration of 'b' hides previous local declaration`

Comment: @RetiredNinja this is correct code according to the standard.

Comment: Using different types [Demo](https://ideone.com/0l7Sdn), or the new c++17 way [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5867f2737b510c4) would show that it is the last which is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (6.4 Selection statements)

> 3 A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced
>   by the decl-specifier-seq or the declarator of the condition) **is in
>   scope from its point of declaration until the end of the
>   substatements** controlled by the condition.

Pay attention to the word **substatements** in plural.

Here is the if-statement definition with the else clause

```
if ( condition ) statement else statement
```

and note from the C++ Standard

> In Clause 6, **the term substatement refers to the contained statement
>   or statements** that appear in the syntax notation.

These statements

```
if (int x = foo()) {
  // ....
}
else if (int x = bar()) {
  // ...
}
else {
  cout << x; // which x here?
}
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
if (int x = foo()) {
  // ....
}
else 
{
    if (int x = bar()) {
      // ...
    }
    else {
      cout << x; // which x here?
    }
}
```

So in the inner else clause the variable `x` denotes the variable declared in the condition of the inner if statement that is the variable declared like

```
if (int x = bar()) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting this reveals the actual scopes:

```
if (int x1 = foo())
{
  // ....
}
else
{
    if (int x2 = bar()) {
      // ...
    }
    else {
      cout << x2; // why x2 is visible here
    }
}
```

`x1` and `x2` are both visible in the last `else` block. If they have the same name then `x2` takes priority over `x1` just as in this case:

```
{
    int a = foo();
    {
        int a = bar();
        //a == bar() value
    }
}
```